# Configure session_store.rb to handle staging and production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a staging and a production environment on my rails 3.1rc6 app which uses subdomains. I've bought and configured different domain names for these environments, because the default something-something.herokuapp.com doesn't play nicely with subdomains.

When I set session_store.rb to this for one environment, everything works fine:

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => '.mystagingdomain.co.uk'
```

But I can't seem to add in a conditional to allow for the environment-specific domain names.

I've tried

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => '.mystagingdomain.co.uk' if Rails.env.staging?
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => '.myproductiondomain.com' if Rails.env.production?
```

which doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `:domain => :all` option. You can also provide a `:tld_length`, if different than 1.

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => :all
```

Here's the relevant Rails code

```
def handle_options(options) #:nodoc:
  options[:path] ||= "/"

  if options[:domain] == :all
    # if there is a provided tld length then we use it otherwise default domain regexp
    domain_regexp = options[:tld_length] ? /([^.]+\.?){#{options[:tld_length]}}$/ : DOMAIN_REGEXP

    # if host is not ip and matches domain regexp
    # (ip confirms to domain regexp so we explicitly check for ip)
    options[:domain] = if (@host !~ /^[\d.]+$/) && (@host =~ domain_regexp)
      ".#{$&}"
    end
  elsif options[:domain].is_a? Array
    # if host matches one of the supplied domains without a dot in front of it
    options[:domain] = options[:domain].find {|domain| @host.include? domain[/^\.?(.*)$/, 1] }
  end
end
```

Otherwise, you should also be able to override the settings in the `config/environments/ENVIRONMENT.rb` file on a per-environment basis.

Comment: Thought I'd add here as this answer helped me. If you're developing with the helper domain lvh.me for your subdomains, it is interpreted via the DOMAIN_REGEXP as being a TLD and so won't mimic example.com, it instead acts like example.com.au so you need to pass tld_length of 1 [Github source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L103)

Answer (score 18):

The following settings has been working fine for me:

config/environments/staging.rb

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => '.mystagingdomain.co.uk'
```

config/environments/production.rb

```
AppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_sample_app_session' , :domain => '.myproductiondomain.com'
```

Comment: I think you need to use either :all or an Array for the value of :domain. Plain string won't work

Comment: Moving this out of `application.rb` has caused errors for me when precompiling assets: `NoMethodError: undefined method merge!' for nil:NilClass`